# Could not resolve hostname

Tags: server, ssh, hostname

I am trying to login to a server using ssh and the console. I have the Ubuntu Raring Ringtail. I get the could not resolve hostname prompt a couple of times and then after some attempts it just works. We have a couple of servers and I have the problem with all of them. No one else at my workplace has this problem. Does this point to a problem with hardware i.e. the switch or is this problem known in "raring ringtail".

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Do you use the same DNS-Server and configuration as the others at your work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the distro to have such a low level issue would be impossible as you would see this forum go wild.

So now you need to fault find.

Best option is to use the IP address instead of the hostname. That way you will rule out any DNS issues or DHCP issues that don't pass the DNS servers correctly.

If you consistently connect when you use an IP address it rules out router, hardware issues. Although the issue might be your computer.

Check your logs for any errors. The `dmesg` command is a good start for seeing errors.

Comment: thanks. After some discussion with my colleagues, I think there is something fishy with the dns server. Thank you for the the quick answer. Wish I could vote up....